# Qt 5.9 OpenGL buffers cleanup

Tags: qt, opengl, vbo, vao, qt5.9

I recently updated to `Qt 5.9`. The application I'm working on uses `QOpenGLWidget` and `QOpenGLBuffers`. I noticed that since `Qt 5.9`, the `QOpenglWidget` destruction is really slow and makes the application exits really slowly.

Any suggestions/ideas to help?

[EDIT] It seems to be linked to the number of `VAO` (`QOpenGLVertexArrayObject`) created. `Qt 5.9` must have changed the way the `VAO`s are cleaned up. Using the `destroy()` function does not change anything.

Comment: That should be really easy to figure out. Use a debug build of Qt, exit the application, stop it in the debugger, and see where it's stuck. No different really than if it was stuck somewhere in your own code.